# extract values from a file and put those values on a particular line from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to get the value 0.98728E-02 from file 1 that is on line 2 and put in place the value of 1,000 of file 2 that is in line 8. How to do file 1 substitution for file 2?

My file 1:

```
Genetic variance(s) for effect  2       
0.98728E-02
Genetic variance(s) for effect  3       
0.56818E-02
```

I need to get the values "0.98728E-02" and put in line in place of the "1.0000" of file 2

My file 2:

```
DATAFILE 
renf90.dat 
NUMBER_OF_TRAITS 
1 
NUMBER_OF_EFFECTS 
9 
RANDOM_RESIDUAL VALUES 
1.0000
RANDOM_GROUP 
2
```

I started doing it in "sed" language, but I do not know what else to do ...

```
sed '23s/1.0000/  .....
```

Final file that I want to have.

```
DATAFILE 
renf90.dat 
NUMBER_OF_TRAITS 
1 
NUMBER_OF_EFFECTS 
9 
RANDOM_RESIDUAL VALUES 
0.98728E-02
RANDOM_GROUP 
2
```

PS: You do not have any constant keywords before or after the lines.
PS: Depending on the output file (File 1), I will need to extract two or three values.

Comment: You could start by providing a sample of the file and your expected output.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the input and output files. Give a bigger example. Do you need to extract only one value or multiple values? Is there always a constant keyword anywhere in the line before or after the lines you are interested from those two files?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's possible with `sed`, but you could easily do it with `awk`:

```bsh
awk 'NR==2 { value=$1 }
     FILENAME=="file2" { if (FNR==8) print value; else print }
' file1 file2 > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 8 of `file2` with the content of line 2 of `file1` with `sed`:

This changes `file2` in place

```
sed -i'' '8s/.*/'"$(sed -n '2p' file1)"'/' file2
```

or the same as above, but write changes to `file2.new`

```
sed '8s/.*/'"$(sed -n '2p' file1)"'/' file2 > file2.new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=`sed -n '2p' file1`

sed  "8s/1.0000/$i/g" file2
```

output

```
DATAFILE 
renf90.dat 
NUMBER_OF_TRAITS 
1 
NUMBER_OF_EFFECTS 
9 
RANDOM_RESIDUAL VALUES 
0.98728E-02
RANDOM_GROUP 
2
```

Note: if you want output should be in file2

```
sed -i   "8s/1.0000/$i/g" file2
```